# How can I get one percent for 3 different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, rgb

I have this code and it's supposed to be a color picking game where you can edit different rgb values with the keys:"asd" and "jkl". I want it to give points based on time and accuracy and stuff but I also want a meter to tell you how close you are to the given color. So if the color is 50,50,50, you should be able to see a percent value for how close you are. So if the color is 51,51,51 it would be like 98% but if the color is 255,255,255 its like 10%. Is this even possible? My current setup is `percent = (r/50)+(g/50)+(b/50)` ( assuming the color is 50,50,50) but it doesn't work at all.

```py
import pygame,sys,time,random
pygame.init()


playerx = 0
playery = 0
sizex=500
sizey=200

r = 255
g = 0
b = 0
color = (r,g,b)
speed = 1
sleep=0.01
col1=random.randint(0,255)
col2=random.randint(0,255)
col3=random.randint(0,255)
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World")
pygame.draw.rect(win, (50,50,50), pygame.Rect(0, 300, sizex, sizey))#do the culoro with col1 and stuff

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                
                percent = (r/50)+(g/50)+(b/50)
                print(percent)
        #if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:



    #win.fill((255,255,255))
    
    pygame.draw.rect(win, color, pygame.Rect(playerx, playery, sizex, sizey))

    #pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,255), pygame.Rect(playerx, playery, sizex/5, sizey/5))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
   


    





    
        
    if  r  +speed <=255 and keys[pygame.K_a]:
        #print("this should be working")
        r+=speed
        color=(r,g,b)
        time.sleep(sleep)
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and g + speed <=255:
        g+=speed
        color=(r,g,b)
        time.sleep(sleep)
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and b +speed<=255:
        b+=speed
        color=(r,g,b)
        time.sleep(sleep)
    if keys[pygame.K_j] and r  - speed >=0:
        r-=speed
        color=(r,g,b)
        time.sleep(sleep)
    if keys[pygame.K_k]and g -speed >=0:
        g-=speed
        color=(r,g,b)
        time.sleep(sleep)
    if keys[pygame.K_l] and b -speed>=0:
        b-=speed
        color=(r,g,b)
        time.sleep(sleep)
    

    

    #time.sleep(0.2)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: There are lots of metrics you could use. The simplest is probably calculating the absolute difference between the guessed value and the correct value for each color, then adding them and dividing them by 3 then again by 2.55.

Comment: @S3DEV I am sorry for the spelling mistakes and I will revise, but the "and stuff" part isn't a requirement, I was just throwing out what I might do later for context on the game, sorry if you misinterpreted that.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis By calculating the absolute difference do you mean adding all of my rgb values and subtracting them by the target combined rgb?

Comment: Subtract the guessed value from the real value, take the absolute of this (i.e. drop any minus signs), repeat for every color, add these together, divide by 3*2.55

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis i tried this but you can just inflate one or two values enough that it will just say 0, even though you dont have the color?

Comment: See my answer for the correct implementation

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Thank you! sorry, i didnt see your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will give you a metric by which you can measure the accuracy of a guess across all three colour channels.

```py
guess = [50, 36, 120]
answer = [83, 21, 187]

accuracy = 0
for channel in range(3):
   accuracy += abs(answer[channel]-guess[channel])
accuracy /= 3*2.55

print(f"Accuracy: {100-accuracy}%")
```

Note the `100-` that turns the measure of inaccuracy into a measure of accuracy.